# I can't apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on dual-boot, but when i try to use `sudo apt update` i receive the following error:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu hirsute
InRelease 
Ign:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04
InRelease                                        
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                    
Hit:4 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                     
Err:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 Release             404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80] 
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu hirsute Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80] Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu hirsute Release'
does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried many solutions but none of them worked.  If I try to
install any app like steam I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libatomic1:i386 :
Depends: gcc-11-base:i386 (= 11-20210417-1ubuntu1) but it is not
installable
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is
not installable  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28)
but it is not installable  libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386
(>= 2.17) but it is not installable  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Depends:
libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libdrm-radeon1:i386 :
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libdrm2:i386 :
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable  libedit2:i386
: Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable 
libelf1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
libexpat1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not
installable  libffi8ubuntu1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it
is not installable  libgl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but
it is not installable  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>=
2.33) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 7) but it is not installable  libglapi-mesa:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it
is not installable  libglvnd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but
it is not installable  libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>=
2.33) but it is not installable  libglx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable  libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends:
libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable  libllvm11:i386 :
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable  libmd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not
installable  libpciaccess0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it
is not installable  libsensors5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33)
but it is not installable  libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-11-base:i386
(= 11-20210417-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 7) but it is not installable  libtinfo6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is
not installable  libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it
is not installable  libvulkan1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29)
but it is not installable
                   Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable or
                               vulkan-icd:i386  libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable  libxau6:i386
: Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable 
libxcb-dri2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not
installable  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it
is not installable  libxcb-glx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4)
but it is not installable  libxcb-present0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386
(>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libxcb-shm0:i386 : Depends:
libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libxcb-sync1:i386 :
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable 
libxcb-xfixes0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not
installable  libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is
not installable  libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it
is not installable  libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but
it is not installable  libxfixes3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4)
but it is not installable  libxinerama1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>=
2.4) but it is not installable  libxshmfence1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not installable  libxxf86vm1:i386 :
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  libzstd1:i386
: Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable  steam:i386 :
Depends: curl:i386
              Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not installable or
                       libgcc1:i386
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: xdg-desktop-portal:i386
              Recommends: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk:i386 or
                          xdg-desktop-portal-backend:i386
              Recommends: xterm:i386 or
                          x-terminal-emulator:i386
              Recommends: zenity:i386  zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct
problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to fix broken repositories first by executing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mc3man/xerus-media
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home\:strycore*.list
```

Then update package lists and install all needed upgrades by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```